# How to build an android app with external libraries using ant (error cannot find symbol)?

Tags: android, ant

I want use ant to build my project with an jar in the libs, the generation of the `build.xml` is successful, but when i execute the `ant release`, there is an error when compiles.

```
[javac] E:\Project\Pascal\Source\workspace\xxx\src\com\xxx\xxx\uti
ls\CommonUtil.java:1267: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : method setOTAMode()
[javac] location: class android.os.RecoverySystem
[javac]             RecoverySystem.setOTAMode();
                     ^
```

But in the eclipse, i can compile successfully. so should i need to add the jar in the build.xml manually, but i was told that the android ant will look after the jar in the libs directory as i found in the base_rules.xml

```
<property name="jar.libs.dir" value="libs" />
<property name="jar.libs.absolute.dir" location="${jar.libs.dir}" />
<property name="native.libs.absolute.dir" location="libs" /
```

So how can i fix this.

Edit: My app is developed for the specified BSP which has the method `setOTAMode`, but i developed with the standard SDK, so in order to compile successfully, i add an jar which has the same package name `android.os.RecoverySystem` in the BSP to fake the java compiler. Then when you run the app in the BSP, the real method in the BSP will be invoked.

So `android.os.RecoverySystem` is defined in the jar and the `setOTAMode` is declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That symbol is not from your JAR, because your JAR does not have `android.os` code in it. `android.os.RecoverySystem` is from the Android SDK. There is no `setOTAMode()` method in the Android SDK for this class, and hence this code will never build. There isn't even a `setOTAMode()` method in the Android source code, AFAICT.

Comment: @dreamtale: You cannot simply add a method to an existing class from a third-party JAR. You are getting the real definition of `RecoverySystem`, which does not have `setOTAMode()`. The AOSP build process includes a means of generating your own version of the Android SDK -- you need to do that and use those results. Or, use reflection to access this method at runtime, rather than trying to reference it directly.

Comment: But why it works when built by the eclipse, what's the difference?

Comment: @dreamtale: Since I have no idea how you configured Eclipse to work, I cannot answer that.

Comment: Add the jar to the Eclipse, then the compile error will disappear, If there are no other ways, i will make my own SDK.